# Spring Boot/Java Heroku Gitlab Continous Deployment

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku, gitlab

I would like to deploy Spring Boot app from gitlab using Gitlab runner to Heroku. I find some tutorials but for ruby.

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8 

before_script:
    - java -version
    - mvn -version

    variables:
      MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/

stages:
  - install
  - test
  - deploy

project-install:
  stage: install
  script:
      - mvn install -P gitlab

backend-test:
 stage: test
  script:
      - mvn verify -pl backend -P itTest,gitlab

heroku-deploy:
????
```

I found maven heroku plugin but my project is under gitlab repository not heroku repository. Moreover i cannot find proper configuration for this [plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.heroku.sdk/heroku-maven-plugin/1.2.0). I want to pass login and password via this plugin to connect to heroku.

My current config:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.0</version>
   <configuration>
       <appName>app-name</appName>
       <processTypes>
           <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.jar</web>
       </processTypes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Maybe I could do continuous deployment. Can anyone help?

Comment: what does the `heroku-deploy:` step look like for the Ruby example?

Comment: I think you probably want to forget the maven plugin and deploy with Git (as I assume the Ruby example did)

Comment: Maybe it is solution but i looking for example of this. I am a beginner and everything what i done i placed above. Moreover when deploy ruby app you install some gems and special plugins for deploying ruby not java

Comment: @codefinger , if you have an idea about this, please post example code

Answer (score 1):

Guess this would help.
This ***works for spring boot application***, where we use ruby 'gem' to deploy the app in heroku.

1. Replace the *"appName"* with the Heroku app you already created at your Heroku dashboard.
2. Also add HEROKU_API_KEY(can be found in heroku) as variable in Gitlab CI/CD settings.

And the maven plugin is NOT needed.

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

maven-build:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package -B"

maven-test:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: test
  script: "mvn test -B"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=<appName> --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: This first build the package on GitLab, and then builds it again on Heroku. It should first build the package on GitLab, and then push it on Heroku.

Comment: How is it possible that I get the error: apt-get : The term 'apt-get' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.